# Agularjs: add a list to sessionStorage only specific to ID

Tags: angularjs, session

In my app, I have many rooms and I need to add participants in that. But need to store the list of participants in session per room.

I'm doing:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("$scope.room.Id",$scope.addedParticipants);
```

The list gets added to all the rooms but not only in that room where it was added.

Please guide me through this. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can try to add an object to you sessionStorage, each room has its own id and it's participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must type the dynamic value not the the value 
like this

```
sessionStorage.setItem("room-id-"+$scope.room.Id,$scope.addedParticipants);
```

when you get

```
sessionStorage.getItem("room-id-"+$scope.room.Id);
```

Comment: this my Plunker try it please [link](https://embed.plnkr.co/T3DHxpaMZ6d1EJvlLiPT/)